# Using AudioQueueNewInput to record stereo

Tags: ios

I would like to use AudioQueueNewInput to create a stereo recording.  I configured it as follows:

```
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    hardwareChannels = 2;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = hardwareChannels;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = (audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * hardwareChannels;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
    OSStatus result =    AudioQueueNewInput(
                            &audioFormat,
                            recordingCallback,
                            (__bridge void *)(self),                    // userData
                            NULL,                   // run loop
                            NULL,                   // run loop mode
                            0,                      // flags
                            &queueObject
                        );
    AudioQueueStart (
        queueObject,
        NULL            // start time. NULL means as soon as possible.
    );
```

I tested this code on an iPhone 6s plus with an external stereo microphone.  It does not seem to record stereo.  Both the left and right channels get identical streams of data.  What else do I need to do to record stereo?